# How MS Ado.Net sync framework works inside?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

In context what is difference between using this way of sync and make backup of db, sync this backup file and restore from this file on other side database. Of course, in context, that size of backup will be no more, for example, 10 MB.

Answer (score 0):

when you use backup, you simply overwrite when you restore. you have no option to resolve conflicts and decide which row to keep (e.g., the row from source was updated and the row on the destination was updated as well)